# QImage definition

Tags: qt, qimage

this command line:
QImage:: QImage (uchar * data, int width, int height, int bytesPerLine, Format format)
Would use is it so?
QImage image = new QImage (buffer, 600, 400, jpg)
the bytesPerLine not they mean well, will the photo occupies kb?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use the bytesPerLine parameter, there is a

```
QImage::QImage ( uchar * data, int width, int height, Format format )
```

constructor.

However, Format is not what you might think. The`format`parameter specifies an enum value which decides over the bit depth etc. I.e. entering`jpg`or`"jpg"`there won't work. Check [Format-enum](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qimage.html#Format-enum) for a list of possible values.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer the best I can considering the fact that your question is very unclear to me.

From the [Qt documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qimage.html#QImage-6):

> bytesPerLine specifies the number of bytes per line (stride)

Also consider that the format argument, which you specified as jpg, must be given as one of the enum values specified [in here](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qimage.html#Format-enum).

Best regards

Comment: sorry, can someone contact me, I could pass the code of my application so that he could give me a hand with the image processing from a buffer.
thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

That's how you would use this constructor:

```
int imageWidth = 800;
int imageHeight = 600;
int bytesPerPixel = 4; // 4 for RGBA, 3 for RGB
int format = QImage::Format_ARGB32; // this is the pixel format - check Qimage::Format enum type for more options
QImage image(yourData, imageWidth, imageHeight, imageWidth * bytesPerPixel, format);
```

You don't specify the image format (png, jpeg, etc.) but the pixel format (RGB, RGBA, etc.)